# Improve performance of obtaining MethodInfo from MethodCallExpression

Tags: c#, reflection, expression

Our UI system can generate a form from a MethodInfo.  Before System.Linq.Expressions, we were getting the MethodInfo using reflection (method 1):

```
MethodInfo info = typeof(ExtensionTestClass).GetMethod("InstanceMethod", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }, null);
```

The bad part about this is that if we changed the signature or name of InstanceMethod, the code would still compile.

Enter expressions.  Now we do this (method 2):

```
 MethodInfo info = GetMethod<ExtensionTestClass>(x => x.InstanceMethod("defaultValue", "defaultValue"));
```

or this (method 3):

```
MethodInfo info = GetMethod<ExtensionTestClass, string, string>(x => x.InstanceMethod);
```

The syntax is "better", we get intellisense, and we get compilation errors if the method doesn't exist or the signature doesn't match.  However, method 2 and method 3 are about 10 to 20 times slower than reflection.

Some numbers (measured with StopWatch):

Single Call:
Method 1:  .0000565
Method 2:  .0004272
Method 3:  .0019222

100000 Calls:
Method 1:  .1171071
Method 2: 1.5648544
Method 3: 2.0602607

We don't actually compile the expression or execute it, and I'm interested if anyone has an explanation for the difference in performance.

UPDATE:  The GetMethod<> code:

Method 2:

```
public static MethodInfo GetMethod<T>(Expression<Action<T>> target)
{
    MethodCallExpression exp = target.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    if (exp != null)
    {
        return exp.Method;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Method 3:

```
public static MethodInfo GetMethod<T, A1, A2>(Expression<Func<T, Action<A1, A2>>> expression)
{
    var lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)expression;
    var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)lambdaExpression.Body;
    var methodCallExpression = (MethodCallExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
    var methodInfoExpression = (ConstantExpression)methodCallExpression.Arguments.Last();
    return (MethodInfo)methodInfoExpression.Value;
}
```

Comment: just asking... have you tried with a custom delegate instead? i.e. `new SomeDelegateType(x.Method)` ?

Comment: Please show the contents of GetMethod. It is hard to analyze code that is not visible...

Comment: @MarcGravell, not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger: @MarcGravell is asking why you don't just use a delegate as a factory instead of relying on methodinfos - especially if you are now using expressions - i.e. at some point you must be calling `MethodInfo.Invoke()` to create the form. If you simply passed a `Func<object> method` as, say, `() => FormType.InstanceMethod()` you can simply call `method()` to create the form - it'll be mega-fast.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan, thanks for the clarification.  We only invoke the method when the form is submitted, not when it is created.  When we do, we don't use MethodInfo.Invoke().  Part of the process not included in the example is the creation of an invoker using Reflection.Emit (it predates the Expression API, although maybe it's time to take another look at it) that we cache and use for any calls to the method.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger yes it might be - you can throw a delegate around in the same way as a `MethodInfo` and invoke it whenever you want - passing the delegate `() => Foo()` as a parameter to a method doesn't invoke anything, it just creates a delegate that can be invoked at some later time

Comment: This [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256199/syntax-alternatives-to-casting-of-dynamic-objects) of mine might shed more light on what I'm doing with it.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's slower because the expression versions do the same reflection (although they might use the IL shortcut `methodof` which has no analogue in C#) in order to create the expression trees, *in addition* to the overhead of creating the trees themselves for every call (I don't think they are cached by the code that the compiler emits); plus you then have to read those trees to get the method back out.

Reflection might be 'slow' but in actual fact it's pretty darned fast; especially since I believe the data, behind the scenes, is cached as well.  Thus once you've called `GetMethod` the second call will be faster.  That provides another compelling proof for why the subsequent expression tree versions are slower - since they are actually doing more work.

If you're comfortable with IL, compile a version with all three and then analyse the compiled image with ILSpy or Reflector (in C# mode both will be clever and re-consitute the expression code back into C#, which is no good; so switch to IL mode) - take a look at the code that's emitted to produce the expression trees and you'll see what I mean.